# Google App ID is missing Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics, ionic-native

I am developing an Ionic APP.
My google-services.json is in the root folder.
But there is the message:

> Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See
> goo.gl/NAOOOI

My code is like this:

```
this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('page_view', {page: "home"})
        .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

I import the

> import { FirebaseAnalytics } from
> '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics/ngx';

as a provider.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I copied my google-services.json to the android/app folder.